# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource ... Cannot find class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I had a project with spring configuration working just fine. However, now I tried to create a maven project and copied all the package to the new maven project, when i run it on a tomcat server i get the exception : canno find class for my sessionFactoryBean.

I don't understand why my maven project is unable to find my annotated class for my springframework configs when the path to class is clearly correct.

my spring config:

```
    <context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Database config -->
<import resource="datasource.xml" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <!-- item -->
            <value>domain.item.Format</value>
            <value>domain.item.Option</value>
            <value>domain.item.Category</value>
            <value>domain.item.Item</value>
            <value>domain.item.ItemPrice</value>
            <value>domain.item.PriceDiscount</value>

            <!-- location -->
            <value>domain.location.Address</value> ....
```

my web.xml

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring.config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Presto.RestServer</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is a screenshot of the project

[image]

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Presto</groupId>
<artifactId>RestServer</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>RestServer</name>

<build>
    <finalName>RestServer</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> </dependency> -->

    <!-- SPRING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.23</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.Class[]] for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [domain.item.Format]

edit:

```
package domain.item;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="FORMAT")
public class Format {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, you'd be better of starting again with a Spring Boot project and dumping your code into it. You'll do away with all the XML configuration, even your pom will be greatly simplified with Boot managing dependency versions - trust me; it will be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue yestarday then i saw this question but not a proper answer.So in future if anyone had this error here is the solution.

I had the same issue.The same error was coming. the problem was in pom.xml.
If you add same dependencies multiple times in your pom.xml you will get this error. In my case i was using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency> 
<dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

which are nothing but same.When i removed dependency with group id jstl the error was gone.
In your case you are using following dependency multiple times.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Remove either of them and hopefully your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Please see below things:**

1. check if `Format` class and other domain classes as well are annotated properly.
2. Check if Component Scan is properly scanning required packages in which these `domain classes` exist.

Alternately you can also add a property below:

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>domain.item</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

inside sessionfactory bean to scan all annotation classes and use `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` for creating SessionFactory

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, can you please explain more in detail for your #2 on how to add the component scan properly? I tried the add the tag @Component in my Format class but that didn't help...

Comment: You have to add something like  <context:component-scan base-package="domain.item" /> for scanning your domain.item package.   Also if you domain is Entity mapping a table  in your database then you have to annotate with @Entity.

Comment: Fairly sure neither of these things is relevant, as the `annotatedClasses` property is passed through to the `SessionFactory` and it is Hibernate that searches for the classes and analyses them.